# How to control Lua script from C (Pause, Resume, Terminate)?

Tags: c, lua

I have a c application that runs some LUA scripts.
Lua scripts run a separate task.

I want to know how to pause Lua script and resume it again, I mean the whole script not just one function?

I want also to terminate a running script completely.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in C (I may be wrong), but why do you need this anyway? you can always interrupt the script in your lua code. I'm quite sure you could do this under some condition.

Comment: The script is running in a separate thread, and my c application is the master, it kinda controls the script and if it takes much time it should have the authority to terminate it, or pause and then resume it later.

Comment: Then have a condition variable to do that for you, and exit the thread if you want to terminate it?

Comment: One idea is to set some debug hooks that fires a callback after a certain number of bytecode is executed. You can use that to get control back from the lua script and do whatever you need from the C side.

Comment: What about using `coroutines` for that?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to create a sandbox where you also track resource utilization. The Lua wiki has [a page on sandboxing](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes).

That page has a fairly comprehensive list of Lua libraries and their relative safety to allow from a sandbox. The best advice is to be careful about what system functions you make available, and especially to create an environment for the sandbox based on a whitelist of functions known to be safe and needed rather than to rely on blacklisting just a few functions you know are dangerous.

However, even an empty environment will still allow a user to deliberately (or accidentally) cause problems. `while(true) end` is the obvious case, but even simple appearing cases can cause trouble. So to avoid that trouble, the usual advice is to do the sort of thing you ask about. Run user-provided scripts in separate threads, and use external controls to halt the threads when necessary.

One way to do that is to set an alarm in the monitor thread when starting a user-script in the sandbox. When the alarm fires, you kill the user script. This technique is described [in the mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-06/msg00133.html). Which brings us to your actual question.

You can use a debug hook set in the Lua instance to regain control periodically, and cleanly exit the thread if a global flag is set (which the alarm handler would do). However, it is still possible to get Lua code stuck inside C code it called, and the debug hook will never trigger. To handle that case, you probably have to use OS level capabilities to terminate the Lua thread, and deal with consequences such as dangling file handles, database connections, or other stranded resources by some clever means.

Answer (score 2):

Couple options:

1. Control the thread via OS functions: put it to sleep or suspend it or make it wait on a semaphore or such. You can resume it using the thread control functions of your OS. You can of course also terminate the thread (kill it).
2. Use flags which your C pushes to Lua as globals and your script checks them and takes action accordingly (suspends work, etc).